# Cont Monad in C++

Tags: c++, templates, monads, continuations

I am attempting to express Haskell's Cont monad in C++ and am confused on translating the typing to C++.

My current approach is to create two classes for the bind and return operations. These hold a value type `A` and return type `R`.

```
template<typename _R, typename _A>
class Cont
{
public:
    typedef _A A;
    typedef _R R;

    virtual R Run(const std::function<R(A)>& k) const=0;
};

template<typename M, typename F,
    typename B = typename std::remove_pointer<typename std::result_of<F(typename M::A)>::type>::type,
    typename R = typename B::R,
    typename A = typename B::A>
class BindCont : public Cont<R, A>
{
    M* m;
    F f;
public:
    explicit BindCont(M* m, const F& f) : m(m), f(f) { }

    virtual R Run(const std::function<R(A)>& k) const
    {
        return m->Run([&](typename M::A x) { return f(x)->Run(k); });
    }
};

template<typename A>
class ReturnCont : public Cont<A, A>
{
    A x;
public:
    explicit ReturnCont(A x) : x(x) { }

    virtual A Run(const std::function<A(A)>& k) const
    {
        return k(x);
    }
};

template<typename M, typename F>
BindCont<M, F>* Bind(M* m, const F& f) { return new BindCont<M, F>(m, f); }

template<typename A>
ReturnCont<A>* Return(A x) { return new ReturnCont<A>(x); }
```

This works for composing objects of the same type, but understandably fails when Bind converts to another type:

```
// This works as the resulting Cont is the same as the Cont being bound.
auto m1 = Bind(Return(4), [](int x)
{
    return (x < 10 ? Return(10) : Return(x));
});

// This fails as when m is run in BindCont, it expects an int, not a const char*
// to be returned.
auto m2 = Bind(Return(4), [](int x)
{
    return (x < 10 ? Return("abc") : Return("xyz"));
});
```

---

### Other Attempts

My first attempt only relied on `A` and determined return type `R` from a generic functor in `Run`:

```
template<typename A>
class ReturnCont : public Cont<A>
{
    A x;
public:
    explicit ReturnCont(A x) : x(x) { }

    template<typename K>
    typename std::result_of<K(A)>::type Run(const K& k) const { return k(x); }
};
```

This however, while it fixes the problem with bind's implementation, requires the compile-time decision of which implementation of `Cont` to use be made at runtime, as the generic `Run` interface cannot be expressed on the base class `Cont`.

---

### Questions

Based on the original code, I have two questions:

- Are the types of `R` and `A` in `BindCont` correct? I have tried adding explicit `R` and `A` types for both `BindCont` and `ReturnCont` but can't seem to get them correct.
- How can `BindCont::Run` be implemented to hook computations of different types together?

---

## Edit

I should also note that having `Run` return `void` works in the original case and allows bind to be correctly implemented. This may be acceptable for certain cases but having a return value is preferable.

Comment: Don't just write Haskell in C++, it doesn't work. C++ is missing important type-system-level features for proper monad-handling. Try to find an idiomatic C++ solution to your original problem (or maybe ask a question about it - about the *problem*, not a solution you think is best).